# Sweetalert hidden behind the modal box always

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sweetalert2

I am using sweetalert v2 and also I am using bootstrap models. The problem is whenever I have bootstrap modals open and I have a sweetalert triggered on the button of modal.

The swal() function is triggered but it is always hidden behind the modal. How to make the sweetalert always on top view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be you are using tabindex on the modal box. Please remove below attributes from your modal division.

```
tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style='z-index:10000;'
```

Comment: how can we fix same in ANGULAR2+ ?